# Likelihood ratio test statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, models, statsmodels

In statsmodels ordinary least squares have likelihood ratio test implemented

```
OLSResults.compare_lr_test(restricted)
```

That is not true for the generalized linear model (GLM).
I tried to implemtent copyng the OLS implementation:

```
from scipy import stats

llf_full = results.llf
llf_restr = results_res.llf
df_full = results.df_resid 
df_restr = results_res.df_resid 
lrdf = (df_restr - df_full)
lrstat = -2*(llf_restr - llf_full)
lr_pvalue = stats.chi2.sf(lrstat, df=lrdf)
lr_pvalue
```

it looks strightforward, but the fact that this is not implemented make me suspicious. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any problem.

Generalized Linear Models are Maximum Likelihood models, if the scale is the one implied by the family.

statsmodels.GLM doesn't currently implement Quasi-Likelihood methods where the scale can deviate from those of the underlying family, e.g. overdispersed Poisson, so the Likelihood Ratio test can be applied.

implementation detail: `compare_lr_test` was supposed to be added for all LikelihoodModels, but I didn't check whether it's correct (or raises exception) for all models that inherit from it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am still a bit confused and small p-values tell me that I should prefer the restricted??? I think in R it is the other-way around.

Comment: If the p-value is small, then we reject the null that the restriction holds, so we should prefer the unrestricted model. The idea is that if the restriction does not hold, then the likelihood ratio test statistic is larger because we "loose" a lot if we impose the restriction.